# Syntax error in PL/pgSQL FOR loop

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, plpgsql

I'm trying to use a `FOR` loop:

```
create or replace function update_revisions() returns trigger as 
$$ 
begin 
    declare col_name declare col_name information_schema.columns%ROWTYPE; 

    for col_name in
       select column_name from information_schema.columns
       where table_name='t'
    loop 
        insert into debug_table values (col_name); 
    end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

But it always says:

> syntax error at or near 'for'

Could someone please give me a hint what's wrong with it?

Comment: Declare section must be placed before `begin` keyword, not after, see general syntax here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-structure.html and a few examples here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-declarations.html

Comment: Why are you using a loop at all? The `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` form of INSERT should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Immediate problem

Invalid syntax. Untangled:

```
create or replace function update_revisions()
  returns trigger as 
$$ 
declare
   col_name information_schema.columns%ROWTYPE; 
begin 
   for col_name in
      select column_name from information_schema.columns
      where table_name='t'
   loop 
      insert into debug_table values (col_name); 
    end loop;
end;
$$  language plpgsql;
```

#### More problems

- Table names are not unique in a Postgres database. More in this recent answer:
  [Behaviour of NOT LIKE with NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818070/behaviour-of-not-like-with-null-values/22818934#22818934)
- The whole approach is inefficient. Use a single `INSERT` statement instead:

```
INSERT INTO debug_table (target_column)  -- with column definition list!
SELECT column_name
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 't'
AND    table_schema = 'public';          -- your schema
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I'll look into the non-unique table names. The insert statement is just there for debugging purposes, not the actual production code.