# where clause not selecting proper rows in a Postgres query

Tags: postgresql

So I have a query where I am attempting to obtain rows that contain the words `citalopram` or the word `celexa` either in the `medication` column or in the `generic` column.

First I tried:

```
where    
    (   medication     ilike '%citalopram%'    or 
        generic        ilike '%citalopram%'    or 
        medication     ilike '%celexa%'        or 
        generic        ilike '%celexa%')
```

And all was find and dandy, except, it also selected rows that contained the medication `escitalopram`. So I changed the query so that it looked like the following:

```
where    
    (   medication     ilike '%citalopram%'    or 
        generic        ilike '%citalopram%'    or 
        medication     ilike '%celexa%'        or 
        generic        ilike '%celexa%')         and 
        medication not ilike '%escitalopram%'    and 
        generic    not ilike '%escitalopram%'
```

Now, sure enough it eliminates the rows containing `escitalopram`, but now sometimes neglects rows that have:

- medication=`CeleXa 40mg oral tablet`, generic=`null`
- medication=`citalopram 40mg oral tablet`, generic=`null`

etc.

Not sure why this might be the problem. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: It is because of generic having a null value - worth reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818070/behaviour-of-not-like-with-null-values

Comment: You might be better off doing a "whole word" search using regex, e.g. `medication ~* '\ycelexa\y'`

Answer (score 0):

why not:

```
where  
concat(' ',medication,' ',generic) ilike '% citalopram%' 
  or 
concat(' ',medication,' ',generic) ilike '% celexa%'
```

putting space before column so if column value starts with the word it still would have  a space